# Retrieving data from sqlitedatabase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want if I click on an list view item the corresponding datas from my database must be displayed in the second activities textview I got the answer but one problem I'm getting only the last data of each category. I need every data of a particular category.

this is my code for retrieving data from database

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.freshdatabase/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "Android.sqlite";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TB_USER = "Users";
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);    
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDB!=null){
        myDB.close();
    }
    super.close();

}
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }

}
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();        

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public List<String> getAllUsers(){
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
        if(c == null) return null;
        String id;
        String name ;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {  
            name = c.getString(1);            
            listUsers.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();        

    return listUsers;
}
public String getPostDesc(String Name){

String  desc = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("Select * from Post INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID=Post.ID WHERE NAME='"+Name+"'" , null);

        if(c == null) return null;
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            desc=c.getString(1);

        System.out.println(desc);

        }
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();
    return desc;        



    }

public String getPostdesc(String name){
    String title="";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("Select * from Post INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID=Post.ID WHERE NAME='"+name+"'" , null);

        if(c == null) return null;


        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            title= c.getString(2);  

        }

            {
}
            c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();        

    return title;
    }
}
```

this is my code for main activity method

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;

ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        dbHeplper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView lvUsers= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    final List<String> listUsers = dbHeplper.getAllUsers();

    if(listUsers != null){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                listUsers);
        lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
    lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                String Desc =(String) dbHeplper.getPostDesc(listUsers.get(position));
                String title1 =(String) dbHeplper.getPostdesc(listUsers.get(position));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "Desc is: " + Desc,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  .show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "Desc is: " + title1,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                          .show();
                Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                newActivity0.putExtra("title", Desc);
                newActivity0.putExtra("title1", title1);
                startActivity(newActivity0);
                }
                }); 


}
```

this is my code for second activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("title");
String message1 = bundle.getString("title1");

TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);    
txtView.setText(message);

TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);    
txtView1.setText(message1);
```

this is my database tables

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `listUsers`?

Comment: Why did you use conflict ids in your 1st database ??

Comment: What does Desc mean? and what is title? you are calling `getPostDesc` if I'm not wrong, so why will it return different values for the same user? Your code is unclear.

Comment: my database structure is this one database with 2 tables first table is category table it contains field ID and NAME .the values from NAme is displayed in my apps listview (category 1 upto 4) its ID is same as that in second table ie to fetch datas according to user clicks on any categories.when user clicks on 1st category it must displays abc and abc1 (ie ID 1) in the second activity.now its displaying only abc1.

Comment: @Anudeep Bulla  desc is my string for holding the value from postname field in the database and title is my string for holding the values from post_desc field.. and can you now check my edited code above??

Comment: Do not repost the questions! You have asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: @Anudeep Bulla getPostDesc and getPostdesc are two methods for returning the values from the second table of the databse when user clicks on any categories..

Comment: @Selvin sorry for the trouble i'm not geting any solution regarding this issue that is why i get forced to repost this question.

Comment: @Thusharaprasad It's **not the correct way** to attract a possible answer. When you have enough reputation, offer a **bounty** on your question, to get attention on it.

Comment: @Thusharaprasad ...1. you are using wrong Adapter, for complex stuff use `ArrayAdapter<POJOClass>` or even better (as you are using SQLite) `(Simple)CursorAdapter` 2. onItemClick should not know about internal stuff of adapter = use `Object itemObject = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` and cast it for the Adapter item class for:`ArrayAdapter<T>`to`T item=(T)itemObject;`, for:`CursorAdapter`to`Cursor item=(Cursor)itemObject;` then use item ... 3. you should not imply column order with `SELECT *` => use `cursor.getColumnIndex();` 4.`SELECT*`is a bad habit

Comment: What is your output ?

Comment: @Selvin Let's not be rude. He already mentioned that he is a newbie, and his reputation suggests he is pretty new here. Offering constructive help will get him to learn faster, than making curt comments.

Comment: then instead asking question here, he should read some guides on http://d.android.com or take some android course ... SO is bad idea for learning (especially if by "learning" he means "writing the code for me")

Comment: @Thusharaprasad what is your output

Comment: Answer your own question, with how you solved it. It would help anyone stumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

i changed my code for retreiving data from db like this..

```
public ArrayList<String> getPostname(String Name) {

    ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from Post INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID=Post.ID WHERE NAME='"+Name+"'" , null);;

    try {
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                          String levelData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("postname"));
                    List.add("" + levelData);

                        }
                          while (c.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                    Log.e("Retrieve Data", "Unable to get Data " + e);
            }

            return List;
        }
```

and in onclick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            ArrayList<String> post_name = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> post_desc = new ArrayList<String>();

            post_name =(ArrayList<String>) dbHeplper.getPostname(listUsers.get(position));
            post_desc =(ArrayList<String>) dbHeplper.getPostdesc(listUsers.get(position));
```

and now its working perfectly..